# BigQuery realtime sync from STAGE to BASE table

Tags: google-bigquery, synchronization

We have data coming from Kafka into one of the staging tables in Bigquery. Also there is another BASE table which is the final table. I need to REALTIME MERGE records from STAGE table to BASE table avoiding duplicates. What do I need to do to achieve this automatic realtime behaviour. Please help.

We have tried Cloud trigger on the STAGE table but that is too much overkill. Need simple cost effective solution. Please help.